# Rename HEAD to lowercase

Tags: git

Can I make git recognize `head` as it does `HEAD`?

I understand this is not recommended, but it would save me moments of frustration.

Comment: A simple hack would be to wrap the `git` executable and `s/head/HEAD/` in the wrapper before passing the arguments on?

Comment: It sometimes will, sort of by accident: on MacOS and Windows systems with case folding, the file name `head` matches the actual file named `HEAD`. That said, see @zoul's suggestion (make yourself a front end `git` that substitutes for you), or use `@` instead of `HEAD`. :-)

Comment: @torek, I think I'll go with `@`; didn't know about it. It does what I wanted and doesn't require anything additional.

@zoul, thanks for the tip, but I think I'll go with the shorter one.